# Web form fill using VBA & Selenium

Tags: html, vba, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have problem with the form filling. Already tried using following methods:

```
driver.FindElementByXPath("//div[@id='s_dane_dokumentu-section?grid-1-grid?c_nr_lrn_komunikatu-control?xforms-input-1']").sendkeys "21123456"
```

and

```
driver.FindElementByXPath("//div[@id='s_dane_dokumentu-section?grid-1-grid?c_nr_lrn_komunikatu-control?xforms-input-1']").value = "21123456"
```

I noticed that ☰ character was displayed in VBA as "?". The full XPath also gives an error. Entire form have a lot of fields, I'm stuck on the first one...

HTML:

```html
<input id="s_dane_dokumentu-section☰grid-1-grid☰c_nr_lrn_komunikatu-control☰xforms-input-1" type="text" name="s_dane_dokumentu-section☰grid-1-grid☰c_nr_lrn_komunikatu-control☰xforms-input-1" value="" class="xforms-input-input" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="true">
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

I might by inclined to use a substring match for the id via css attribute = value selector with $ ends with operator. In addition, add in the class and the type selector for the shown input element for extra specification.

```
driver.FindElementByCss("input.xforms-input-input[id$=xforms-input-1]").sendkeys "21123456"
```

You could also just use a single quote enclosed (for the value) attribute = value selector for the id. The prevents the WebDriver being thrown by the special characters.

```
driver.FindElementByCss("[id='s_dane_dokumentu-section☰grid-1-grid☰c_nr_lrn_komunikatu-control☰xforms-input-1']").sendkeys "21123456"
```

Comment: It works with the first one. Before was necessary to enter the iframe. Thanks a lot!

Comment: you are most welcome